# PHP Form Redirect After Submission

Tags: php, html, forms

I have been trying to get my PHP contact form to go to a different page after it is properly submitted. Currently this form works great as a means to send an email to my account and inform the user it has not been properly filled out, adding a redirect has not worked well though.

Doing research i have heard many people mention the header() command and how it works for redirects but have been unsuccessful in getting it to work with my code. I have updated the code to represent how i used the header command. Currently all it does is send my page back to itself and starts the form over. Dreamweaver does not show any errors in code

Any help would be appreciated. I have placed my code below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="startup/flat-ui/images/favicon.ico">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="startup/flat-ui/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="startup/flat-ui/css/flat-ui.css">
        <!-- Using only with Flat-UI (free)-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="startup/common-files/css/icon-font.css">
        <!-- end -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="startup/common-files/css/animations.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
        
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="page-wrapper">
<section id="contactform" class="contacts-1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <h3>Step 1: Information Form</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
             <?php
                            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
                            // Form variables
                            // req: name, ship, ctname, ctnum, email
       $goto_after_mail = "http://www.recycleoilsep.com/step2.html";
       $formName = filter_var($_POST['formName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
       $formShip = filter_var($_POST['formShip'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
       $formCity = filter_var($_POST['formCity'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
       $formState = filter_var($_POST['formState'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
       $formZip = filter_var($_POST['formZip'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
       $formCtname = filter_var($_POST['formCtname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
       $formCtnum = filter_var($_POST['formCtnum'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
       $formEmail = filter_var($_POST['formEmail'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
       
                            // CAPTCHA
                            require_once('captcha/recaptchalib.php');
                            $privatekey = "";
                            $resp = recaptcha_check_answer(
                            $privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]
                            );
                            // Form validation
                            $nameError = $formName == "";
                            $shipError = $formShip == "";
       $cityError = $formCity == "";
       $stateError = $formState == "";
       $zipError = $formZip == "";
                            $ctnameError = $formCtname == "";
                            $ctnumError = $formCtnum == "";
       $emailError = $formEmail == "";
       
                            $captchaError = !($resp->is_valid);
                            $hasError = $nameError || $shipError || $cityError || $stateError || $zipError || $ctnameError || $ctnumError || $emailError ;
                            if(!$hasError && !$captchaError) {
                            $headers  = 'From: '.$formName.' <'.$formEmail.'>' . "\r\n";
                            $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $formEmail . "\r\n";
                            $headers .= 'Return-Path: ' . $formEmail . "\r\n";
                            $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
                            $body =
                            " 
       <p><b>Company Name: </b>$formName</p>
       <p><b>Pickup Address: </b>$formShip</p>
       <p><b>Pickup City: </b>$formCity</p>
       <p><b>Pickup State: </b>$formState</p>
       <p><b>Pickup Zip: </b>$formZip</p>
       <p><b>Contact Name: </b>$formCtname</p>
       <p><b>Contact Phone: </b>$formCtnum</p>
       <p><b>Contact Email: </b>$formEmail</p><br>
       
       ";
                            mail(
                            "info@website.com",
                            "A new request from website.com!",
                            $body,
                            $headers
                            );
                            header("location: ".$goto_after_mail);
                            } else {
                            echo "<p>There was an error submitting the form. Please check all the marked fields.</p>";
                            if ($captchaError) {
                            echo "<p>Captcha error. Please type the checkwords again.</p>";
                            }
                            }
                            }
                            ?>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        var RecaptchaOptions = {
                        theme : 'clean'
                        };
                        </script>       
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <form id="contactForm" action="" method="post">
                                <div class="control-group<?php if ($nameError) echo " error"; ?>">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="formName"><strong>Company Name</strong></label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                     <input  type="text" name="formName" value="<?php echo $formName; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group<?php if ($shipError) echo " error"; ?>">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="formShip"><strong>Address for Pickup</strong></label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                     <input  type="text" name="formShip" value="<?php echo $formShip; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                 <div class="control-group<?php if ($cityError) echo " error"; ?>">
                                     <label class="control-label" for="formCity"><strong>City</strong></label>
                                     <div class="controls">
                                      <input  type="text" name="formCity" value="<?php echo $formCity; ?>">
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                 <div class="control-group<?php if ($stateError) echo " error"; ?>">
                                     <label class="control-label" for="formState"><strong>State</strong></label>
                                     <div class="controls">
                                      <input  type="text" name="formState" value="<?php echo $formState; ?>">
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                 <div class="control-group<?php if ($zipError) echo " error"; ?>">
                                     <label class="control-label" for="formZip"><strong>Zip</strong></label>
                                     <div class="controls">
                                      <input  type="text" name="formZip" value="<?php echo $formZip; ?>">
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                                </div>  
                                 <div class="control-group<?php if ($ctnameError) echo " error"; ?>">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="formCtname"><strong>Contact Name</strong></label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                     <input  type="text" name="formCtname" value="<?php echo $formCtname; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                                 <div class="control-group<?php if ($ctnumError) echo " error"; ?>">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="formCtnum"><strong>Contact Number</strong></label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                     <input type="text" name="formCtnum" value="<?php echo $formCtnum; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="control-group<?php if ($emailError) echo " error"; ?>">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="formEmail"><strong>Contact Email</strong></label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                     <input type="email" name="formEmail" value="<?php echo $formEmail; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               <br>
                                
                                
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <div class="controls">
          <?php
                                        // load recaptcha file
                                        require_once('captcha/recaptchalib.php');
                                        // enter your public key
                                        $publickey = "-";
                                        // display recaptcha test fields
                                        echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <br />
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Go To Step 2" tabindex="5" id="submit" name="submit">
                                        
                                        <a href="step2.html">Click Here to go to Step 2</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                         </form>
                        </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to redirect, as in your code?

Comment: You don't use ``header()`` in you'r code, so make an example and explain what "does not work" mean

Comment: Ive tried using it in serveral locations but the form just redirects to itself. I figuring posting the base code without the header would be a cleaner way to show what i have and not create any confusion. 

PE MapModder. Im trying to redirect to a HTML page

Comment: if a header didn't work for you, then chances are you're outputting before header but don't know because you're not checking for errors.

Comment: What does  "outputting before header" mean? Ive read that but dont understand how that relates to the form. Im a graphic designer by trade and have been learning code slowly